# J2me mobile app run in sony ericson but not run in nokia mobile.Help me to solve it?

Tags: java-me, nokia-s40

I am developing a mobile app using j2me. It works fine in "sony ericsson z530i". It works fine in "Nokia c2-00" mobile before 1 week. But I run the app now in nokia phone after sometime in the middle of app automatically my nokia phone switches off. I cannot resolve it but it works fine in sony ericsson mobile. I think I need to change some phone setting or the phone is in problem? I cannot find a solution so please help me solve the issue. I am using "Nokia c2-00" mobile which had "S40" sdk.

Comment: what is the battery level in your nokia mobile and what api's you are calling when it goes switch off ?

Comment: I will check my MIDP version and CLDC.My midp version is 2.0 and cldc is 1.1

Comment: I check the battery status.It will high,full charged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.The problem is not in mobiles is in my application.It will not run due to ran out of heap memory.

Now i modified my code with respect to decrease the memory leak.Now its working in all mobiles which have the configuration cldc1.1 and midp2.0

Answer (score 0):

Some time problem may be in MIDP version in the mobile application check whether property and select MIDP as 2.0.